# Doubt on size of the automorphism of regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, isomorphism-testing

Let $X= (V,E)$ be a input graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$.  Now we can define the  AUT$(X)= \{\sigma | X^{\sigma} = X\}$. We know that if $X= K_n$ (complete graph with $n$ vertices) its AUT$(X) =S_n$ (symmetric group) but while I was watching the videos of babai on his recent result on graph isomorphism I did not get what he meant by "if a graph is regular then it does not have many automorphisms ".

**Link :** Watch at 40:12 [(Graph Isomorphism in Quasipolynomial Time I)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYIhA3O9Nz0&t=4299s)

Comment: No, it's not true

Comment: "Not to have many automorphisms" is not a mathematical statement.

Comment: Yes but I am not getting why he said this thing

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question (including title).

Comment: Your observation on the complete graph is correct. So one of the following holds (a) Babai does not know the complete graph (b) Babai knows the complete graph but was unable to compute its automorphism group (c) Babai's statement you quote is informal and not to be interpreted literally, but rather by "Usually, when a graph is regular, it does not have many automorphisms".

Comment: To be fair, he says "a regular graph does not have _too_ many automorphisms", which is a considerably more lenient statement. I couldn't find the moment when he clarifies this remark though.

Comment: I agree with YCor, in context, I take Babai to mean that regular graphs have few automorphisms on average, which I think is important to him to point out  because that fact will cause problem for him in the rest of the proof (so I take him to be inserting a casual remark of why he did not go with a seemingly simpler route for his proof).

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the sample space to be the $d$-regular graphs on $n$ labeled vertices then there will be various automorphism classes (The number being the unlabeled $d$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices.) The larger the automorphism group,  the smaller the class. So, although some have a large automorphism group, they are  relatively rare (assuming that $d$ is at least $3$ and $n$ at least $2d$, say.) I’m sure that the expected size of the automorphism group (fixing $d$) goes to $1.$

On $6$ vertices there are two classes of $3$-regular graphs. Complete bipartite with $72$ automorphism and $10$ labelings and a triangular prism with $12$ automorphism and $60$ labelings. So the expected number of automorphisms is $1440/70=20\ 4/7.$

According to the OEIS there are $19355$ labelled $3$-regular graphs on $8$ vertices. There can be as many as $2\cdot 4!^2=1152$ automorphisms, but that is just for the $8!/1152=35$ labelings of the union of two tetrahedra. The next largest possibility is $48$ automorphisms which occurs just for the $8!/48=840$ labelings of a cube. The other $18580$ graphs in the [sample space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs) have $4,12$ or $16$ automorphisms. The number of labelings of the one class with $4$ automorphisms is $8!/4=10800.$ That is over half the sample space.

I suppose the average number of automorphisms (since there are $6$ classes) is $8!\frac6{19355}$ which is almost exactly $25/2.$ if we restrict to connected cubic graphs on $8$ vertices that goes down to $8!\frac5{19320}$ which is a little over $10.$